# Error when running spawns in Erlang module

Tags: erlang

When running this module:

```
-module(cbbs).

-export([ahu/0, duct/1, simulate/0, room1/1, vent1/0]).

duct(P) ->
      if
      P>=250 ->
        apid ! full,
        io:format("Full Pressure~n", []),
        receive
            gia ->
            vent1 ! {gia, self()},
            io:format("Feeding Vent1~n", []),
        duct(P-2)
        end;

      true ->
        apid ! {pressurise, self()},
        receive
            pressurise ->
                io:format("Receiving Pressure~n", []),
                duct(P + 1);
            gia ->
                vent1 ! gia,
                io:format("Feeding Vent1~n", []),
                duct(P - 1)
        end
    end.


ahu() ->
    receive
        full ->
            io:format("Stopped~n", []);
        {pressurise, duct} ->
            io:format("Pressurising~n", []),
                duct ! pressurise,
            ahu()       
    end.


vent1() ->
    receive
        {toohot, room1} ->
            io:format("Open~n", []),
            duct ! gia;

        {roomtemp, room1} ->
            io:format("Closed~n", []);

        {gia, duct} ->
            io:format("Feeding Room1~n", []),
            room1 ! ga,
            vent1()
        end.

room1(T) ->
     if
     T >= 20 ->
           vent1 ! {toohot, self()},
           io:format("R1 Too Hot~n", []),
           receive
            ga ->
            io:format("Cooling R1~n", []),
            room1(T-1)
        end;

     true ->
        vent1 ! {roomtemp, self()},
        io:format("Room Temperature~n", []),
        room1(T+1)

    end.

simulate() ->
        register(apid, spawn(cbbs, ahu, [])),
        register(vent1, spawn(cbbs, vent1, [])),
        register(duct, spawn(cbbs, duct,[0])),
        register(room1, spawn(ccbs, room1, [20])).
```

I get this error:

```
cbbs:simulate().
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  register/2
        called as register(apid,<0.292.0>)
     in call from cbbs:simulate/0 (cbbs.erl, line 76)
```

I can't seem to understand any further what it is asking of me. This is meant to simulate a concurrent building services and making this somewhat complicated in terms of communication.  I can't however, find out what the problem is here, and therefore can't move on to finding what other problems there are !

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

EDIT:

I get the following from running first time:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 10-May-2017::15:36:54 ===
Error in process <0.69.0> with exit value:
{undef,[{ccbs,room1,[20],[]}]}
```

Followed by the error previously mentioned.

Comment: Looks like another process is already registered as `apid` before that line executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spelled your module name `cbbs` incorrectly on the last line in `simulate()`:

```
   register(room1, spawn(ccbs, room1, [20])).
```

The first time you run your program, you will get an error on that line.  The second time you run your program, you will get an error on the first line of `simulate()`:

```
register(apid, spawn(cbbs, ahu, [])),
```

That's because the first time you run your program, your registered processes get stuck in infinite loops, so they live on forever in the shell after your program ends.  Consequently, when you run `simulate()` a second time, the names you try to register will already be the names of running processes (recompiling won't help).  Because of the problems in your program, in order to run your program a second time, you need to kill the erlang shell and start a fresh erlang shell.  That will terminate the left over processes from the first time you ran your program.

Try this:

1. Correct the spelling error.
2. Start a new erlang shell.
3. Run `simulate()`.
4. Use the `i()` command in the shell to examine the currently running processes.

Here's an example:

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

-----Now, do some Erlang for great Good!------

Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)

1> c(cbbs).
{ok,cbbs}

2> cbbs:simulate().
R1 Too Hot
ok

3> i().
Pid                   Initial Call                          Heap     Reds Msgs
Registered            Current Function                     Stack              
<0.0.0>               otp_ring0:start/2                      233      606    0
init                  init:loop/1                              2              
<0.1.0>               erts_code_purger:start/0               233        8    0
erts_code_purger      erts_code_purger:loop/0                  3              
<0.4.0>               erlang:apply/2                        4185   596196    0
erl_prim_loader       erl_prim_loader:loop/3                   5              
<0.30.0>              gen_event:init_it/6                    610      226    0
error_logger          gen_event:fetch_msg/5                    8              
<0.31.0>              erlang:apply/2                        1598      416    0
application_controlle gen_server:loop/6                        7              
<0.33.0>              application_master:init/4              233       64    0
                      application_master:main_loop/2           6              
<0.34.0>              application_master:start_it/4          233       59    0
                      application_master:loop_it/4             5              
<0.35.0>              supervisor:kernel/1                    610     1700    0
kernel_sup            gen_server:loop/6                        9              
<0.36.0>              erlang:apply/2                       10958   130910    0
code_server           code_server:loop/1                       3              
<0.38.0>              rpc:init/1                             233       21    0
rex                   gen_server:loop/6                        9              
<0.39.0>              global:init/1                          233       44    0
global_name_server    gen_server:loop/6                        9              
<0.40.0>              erlang:apply/2                         233       21    0
                      global:loop_the_locker/1                 5              
<0.41.0>              erlang:apply/2                         233        3    0
                      global:loop_the_registrar/0              2              
<0.42.0>              inet_db:init/1                         233      249    0
inet_db               gen_server:loop/6                        9              
<0.43.0>              global_group:init/1                    233       55    0
global_group          gen_server:loop/6                        9              
<0.44.0>              file_server:init/1                     376      554    0
file_server_2         gen_server:loop/6                        9              
<0.45.0>              supervisor_bridge:standard_error/      233       34    0
standard_error_sup    gen_server:loop/6                        9              
<0.46.0>              erlang:apply/2                         233       10    0
standard_error        standard_error:server_loop/1             2              
<0.47.0>              supervisor_bridge:user_sup/1           233       53    0
                      gen_server:loop/6                        9              
<0.48.0>              user_drv:server/2                     1598     3850    0
user_drv              user_drv:server_loop/6                   9              
<0.49.0>              group:server/3                         233      210    0
user                  group:server_loop/3                      4              
<0.50.0>              group:server/3                         987    13450    0
                      group:server_loop/3                      4              
<0.51.0>              erlang:apply/2                        4185     9974    0
                      shell:shell_rep/4                       17              
<0.52.0>              kernel_config:init/1                   233      193    0
                      gen_server:loop/6                        9              
<0.53.0>              supervisor:kernel/1                    233       56    0
kernel_safe_sup       gen_server:loop/6                        9              
<0.57.0>              erlang:apply/2                        1598    20441    0
                      c:pinfo/1                               50              
<0.64.0>              cbbs:ahu/0                             233        2    1
apid                  cbbs:ahu/0                               1              
<0.65.0>              cbbs:vent1/0                           233        2    1
vent1                 cbbs:vent1/0                             1              
<0.66.0>              cbbs:duct/1                            233        2    0
duct                  cbbs:duct/1                              2              
<0.67.0>              cbbs:room1/1                           233       15    0
room1                 cbbs:room1/1                             2              
Total                                                      31365   779424    2
                                                             228              
ok
4>
```

In the `i()` output, the heading for the first column is:

```
Pid
Registered
```

That column lists all the *process identifiers* (Pid's) of the processes currently running in the shell along with the registered name of the process underneath the Pid--if the process is registered.  You can see that your registered processes are listed at the bottom of the first column.  Your program has terminated, but those processes are still running in the shell.

In the `i()` output, the heading for the second column is:

```
Initial Call
Current Function
```

`Initial Call` is the function that you called to start the process, e.g. `spawn(ccbs, room1, [20])`, and underneath that is the function that is currently executing in that process.  For example, if `room1()` called a helper function to do the looping, say `loop()`, then in column two you would see:

```
cbbs:room1/1
cbbs:loop/1
```

---

The reason that your processes get stuck in an infinite loop is because the patterns in your receive clauses are faulty.   For instance, when you send a message here:

```
room1(T) ->
     if
     T >= 20 ->
           vent1 ! {toohot, self()},
```

`self()` does not return `room1`, so in the receive clause here:

```
vent1() ->
    receive
        {toohot, room1} ->
            io:format("Open~n", []),
            duct ! gia;
```

the pattern `{toohot, room1}` will not match the message that `room1()` sent. `self()` actually returns a Pid--not a registered name.  A Pid converted to a string for output looks like:  `<0.66.0>` (but try to remember that a Pid isn't a string, so you can't write `"<0.66.0>"` in your code for a Pid).

You need to change the pattern in your receive clause.  You could change the pattern to:

```
vent1() ->
    receive
        {toohot, _From} ->  #<*** HERE
            io:format("Open~n", []),
            duct ! gia;
```

That receive pattern will match a tuple whose whose second term is *anything*.  Or, you could change the receive pattern to:

```
vent1() ->
    Room1 = whereis(room1),  #<***HERE
    receive
        {toohot, Room1} ->   #<***AND HERE
            io:format("Open~n", []),
            duct ! gia;
```

`whereis()` returns the Pid of a registered name.  In this case, the receive pattern will only match a tuple whose second element is the Pid of the `room1` process.

---

Also, `if-statements` are frowned upon in erlang.  Check out the following alternative for `room1()`:

```
room1(T) when T >= 20 ->
    vent1 ! {toohot, self()},
    io:format("R1 Too Hot~n", []),
    receive
        ga ->
            io:format("Cooling R1~n", []),
            room1(T-1)
    end;
room1(T) ->
    vent1 ! {roomtemp, self()},
    io:format("Room Temperature~n", []),
    room1(T+1).
```

Function clauses are matched in the order that they are written in your code.  Therefore, when you call `room1()`, first erlang will try to match the function clause:

```
room1(T) when T >= 20 ->
```

If `T` is smaller than 20, that function clause won't match, so erlang will proceed to the next function clause:

```
room1(T) ->
```

That function clause will match any single argument, so it will execute.  Notice that a semi-colon separates function clauses rather than a period.  If you accidentally use a period, you will get the error:

> function room1/1 already defined

If it feels natural for you to write an `if-statement` first, then go ahead and do that...but immediately work on converting the `if-statement` to a series of `function clauses`.  After you do the conversions for awhile, I think your mind will adapt to thinking in terms of `function clauses` rather than `if-statements`.

---

Also, I see that you are doing the same thing I used to do:

```
io:format("R1 Too Hot~n", []),
```

There is an additional one argument form of `io:format()`, so you can just write:

```
io:format("R1 Too Hot~n"),
```

which is less painful to type.

Comment: In general, the process should register itself (because then it knows that it's not dead...), and you should use the `?MODULE` macro.

Comment: Beginners should _always_ use the `?MODULE` macro; it protects against typos.

Comment: Many Thanks to you @7stud !!!!! Absolutely amazing answer. Will try and get this to work now :).

Comment: @GabrielSeite,  If you run into anymore problems, post a comment directed at me, and I'll have another look at your program.  Good luck!

Comment: @7stud Thanks to your help I have managed to get the system to run concurrently with 3 vents and 3 rooms. Let me know if you would like the solution, I would be happy to send it your way !

Answer (score 1):

The register call can fail if the name is already busy or if the process has died before you had time to register it. You can check the first case with whereis(ProcessName), and the second case with erlang:is_process_alive(Pid).

Comment: Thank you for your reply !

It's weird because it return true when I simulate, and then prints this:

    =ERROR REPORT==== 10-May-2017::15:36:54 ===
    Error in process <0.69.0> with exit value:
    {undef,[{ccbs,room1,[20],[]}]}

If I simulate again, it gives me the error previously mentioned